# navigation menu with jQuery

Tags: jquery, menu

I have created a simple navigation menu. And now I want to add "active" class to relevant "a" when hover child UL. How can i do it? 
I can't find solution of it with CSS.
My Codes Here :

HTML :

```
                      <nav class = 'main_navigation'>
                           <ul class = 'parent_ul'>
                               <li><a  href="#">Home</a></li>
                               <li><a  href="#">Themes</a>
                                       <ul class = 'child_ul'>
                                          <li><a href='#'>Theme 1</a></li>
                                          <li><a href='#'>Theme 2</a></li>
                                          <li><a href='#'>Theme 3</a></li>
                                          <li><a href='#'>Theme 4</a></li>
                                       </ul>
                                   </li>
                                   <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                                   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                    </nav>
```

.active class:

```
.active{
 background:red;
 }
```

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, it would be kind to mark the answer as Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery:

```
$( ".parent_ul a" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "active" );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "active" );
  }
);
```

Jquery hover() documentation:
https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: That was my first thought by using jQuery too.  I submitted my answer with CSS because the question mentionned he didn't know how to do it with CSS

Answer (score 0):

Without using javascript or jQuery, if your need is simply to change the look of the link when you "hover" the ul, you can do it only in CSS.

CSS example :

```
nav.main_navigation a:hover {
  background:red;
}
```

You could even add a second CSS to emphasize the submenu :

```
nav.main_navigation li:hover {
  background: pink;
}
```